# Jquery глобальная переменная

Tags: jquery

```
  $("селектор").hover(
        // создание переменной, и занесение в нее информацию
        }
    );

    $("селектор").click(
        // сюда действия использующую переменную 
        }
    );
```

Подскажите, как можно использовать переменную из первого события во втором событии?

Comment: Мдя… Вы точно знаете самые элементарные основы Яваскрипта? Может все же подучить матчасть?

Comment: может все таки я понимаю это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = false;
$("селектор").hover(function() { a = true; }, function() { a = false; });
$("селектор").click(function() { console.log(a); });
```

Ну и текстом - объявите переменную *вне*, но *в зоне видимости* обоих callback'ов.